# Where do I write and link jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I just learned how to write jQuery but I have no idea where to write jQuery or how to link it to my HTML. It would be great if you could include a lot of detail.

Comment: Most any jQuery tutorial will cover how to load jQuery itself, and where/how to write the code that uses jQuery.

Comment: Um, code academy just wrote all the jquery in a java script file and didnt include any links in the html

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 - Include jQuery in the page.  This is accomplished by simply creating a `script` tag which links to the library.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

This is *commonly* done in the `head` element of the page, but it doesn't *need* to be.  Technically it can be done anywhere on the page.  And for pages which want to load UI resources quickly and *then* invoke code, this can often be done at the end of the page body.

It's not necessary to link to the CDN version as I'm doing here, you can also maintain local copies of jQuery.  Or you can link to another version, or another CDN, etc.

Step 2 - Write jQuery code.  This can be done in any code block *after* the above line that includes the library.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // code
    });
</script>
```

jQuery code is just JavaScript code which depends on the jQuery library.  So you can write it anywhere you write JavaScript code.  Since it depends on a specific library, it simply needs to exist after the library is loaded (since JavaScript is parsed in the order in which it's written).

Answer (score 3):

In the `<head>` of your page, include a link to jquery's core, like so:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>`

then write your code within `<script>` tags in the head.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //your code here
    });
  </script>
  <!-- whatever else -->
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write it in side the  tag, where you would write the javascript usually.

You can add an external file like below-

```
 <script src="Scripts/abc.js"></script>
```

or inside your aspx,htmletc file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // your code
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it directly to the HTML doc inside `<script>` tags or link with `<script src="javascript.js"></script>`. You should probably review that course fully to make sure you catch important concepts like that.